# Nav footer header etc tags doesn't do anything?

Tags: html, css, tags, navbar, semantics

there i am new on StackOverFlow.

I just wanted to ask these tags as Nav, footer, header etc are necessary? It doesn't do anything special except telling that this section is about that right? I heard its good for seo ranking something like that though.

And i wanted to ask this too that i saw someone using nav then #navbar why he couldn't use navbar directly as id?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunatly SO is not a tutorial, guide or forum. Its for a specific coding issues. As such your question would not fit. Those tags are just for ordering your sturcture and certain frameworks actually "require/use" them. `<nav>` has no ID by default. To be specific, you could use those tags multiple time, sometimes using an ID has its advantages for calling that element via scripts (`getElementById`) instead of using `querySelector`.

Comment: PS: Another reason to give the navbar an ID is to call the navbar with an anchor: `<a href="#navbar"></a>`. For example as an easy way to use a scroll to navbar button.

Answer (score -1):

Those are HTML Semantic Elements. The HTML5 specification introduced several semantic sectioning elements to help organize the structure of documents. Semantic sectioning elements are specifically designed to communicate structural meaning to browsers and other technologies interpreting the document on behalf of users, such as screen readers and voice assistants.

Those tags are not necessary but it helps to organize the structure of documents.

Check out to know more details - [HTML Semantic Elements - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

Comment: The are not necessary, They are certainly helpful in most cases but not necessary as their is no requirement to use them at all.

Comment: @tacoshy totally agreed!!